# Could a wish spell make someone who is not able to cast the wish spell, able again?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, balance, wish

This is a weird question, I know, it's simply food for thought. It states in the PHB that casting a wish spell for any other effect than duplicating another spell causes a stress that can, among other things, cause you to never be able to cast the spell again. Now lets say you have two wizards who can cast this spell and one loses its ability to cast the wish spell, would the other wizard be able to use the wish spell to let the other mage regain it's ability to cast the spell?

Comment: Hello and welcome! If you have time make sure to check the [tour] to find out more about how this site works (you also earn a badge!). I am afraid that as it stands this question risks getting closed for being opinion-based, which our stack format does not handle well. You will probably have better luck asking about this in [an rpg forum](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5449/ive-been-told-my-question-is-better-suited-to-a-forum-but-where-should-i-go)

Comment: Welcome indeed! the tour goes into this a little bit, but the stack is not like a traditional discussion board, in that we focus almost exclusively on well defined questions with objectively supported answers. As such, questions that ask for opinions, or are subjective in nature are usually closed. In your case, we might be able to answer "Can a wish spell restore the ability to cast wish" but we almost certainly cannot give you our own opinions on the matter in a main site answer.

Comment: I edited your question to delete the part where you ask for an opinion. This should suffice the requirements of the site. If you think that the edit changed the question in any way, you can revert it at any point in time.